# Best method for 2M calculations

Tags: vba, nested-loops

I'm a entry level programmer, mostly all self taught.  I have some code which is trying to run through about 2,000,000 scenarios to find the lowest value based on about six various scenarios (age, years at job, investment strategy, etc).

Currently my code is setup :

```
Sub DetermineAllReturnRequired()

Dim wsSummary As Worksheet: Set wsSummary = Worksheets("Summary")
Dim wsLowestReturn As Worksheet: Set wsLowestReturn = Worksheets("LowestReturn")

'Loop variables
Dim i As Double, j As Long, k As Long, c As Long, g As Long, w As Integer, a As Integer, y As Integer, b As Integer

'Variables same for both grades
Dim Interest As Double
Dim Years As Integer
Dim Age As Integer
Dim Found(0 To 1) As Range
Dim Arr_HighestSavings(0 To 1, 0 To 12, 20 To 40, 1 To 7, 0 To 1, 0 To 1, 0 To 1) As Double ' (c - continuation, k - years served, j - year retired, a - intersect options (60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90), g = grade, w - withdraw 4%, b - adjusted for inflation)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Clears values
If wsLowestReturn.Cells(4, 2).Value <> Null Then
    For j = 20 To 40
        For k = 0 To 12
            For g = 0 To 1
                For c = 0 To 1
                    For w = 0 To 1
                        For b = 0 To 1
                            For a = 1 To 7
                                wsLowestReturn.Cells((k * 9) + (3 + a), j - 18 + c * 52 + g * 26 + b * 104 + w * 208).Value = Null
                            Next a
                        Next b
                    Next w
                Next c
            Next g
        Next k
    Next j
End If


'interest
For i = 0.05 To 0.15 Step 0.0001

    wsSummary.Range("G7") = i
    Interest = i

    ' years served when retire
    For j = 20 To 30

        wsSummary.Range("G4") = j
        Years = j

        'current years served
        For k = 0 To 12

            wsSummary.Range("G5") = k
            wsSummary.Range("G15") = k

            'grade (officer,0, enlisted, 1)
            For g = 0 To 1
                    If g = 0 Then
                        wsSummary.Range("G10") = "Officer"
                        wsSummary.Range("G6") = "22"
                    Else
                        wsSummary.Range("G10") = "Enlisted"
                        wsSummary.Range("G6") = "18"
                    End If

                'continuation pay (yes, 0, no, 1)
                For c = 0 To 1
                        If c = 0 Then
                            wsSummary.Range("G17") = "Yes"
                        Else
                            wsSummary.Range("G17") = "No"
                        End If
                    'withdrawal rate (0 = yes, no, 1)
                    For w = 0 To 1
                        If w = 0 Then
                            wsSummary.Range("G21") = "Yes"
                        Else
                            wsSummary.Range("G21") = "No"
                        End If



                Set Found(0) = wsSummary.Range("F38")

                If Found(0) = 60 Or Found(0) = 65 Or Found(0) = 70 Or Found(0) = 75 Or Found(0) = 80 Or Found(0) = 85 Or Found(0) = 90 Then
                    a = Found(0) / 5 - 11
                    b = 0
                    If Interest < Arr_HighestSavings(c, k, j, a, g, w, b) Or Arr_HighestSavings(c, k, j, a, g, w, b) = 0 Then
                        Arr_HighestSavings(c, k, j, a, g, w, b) = Interest
                        wsLowestReturn.Cells((k * 9) + 3, 1) = k
                        wsLowestReturn.Cells((k * 9) + (3 + a), j - 18 + c * 52 + g * 26 + b * 104 + w * 208) = Round(Arr_HighestSavings(c, k, j, a, g, w, b), 4)
                    End If
                End If

                Set Found(1) = wsSummary.Range("I38")

                If Found(1) = 60 Or Found(1) = 65 Or Found(1) = 70 Or Found(1) = 75 Or Found(1) = 80 Or Found(1) = 85 Or Found(1) = 90 Then
                    a = Found(1) / 5 - 11
                    b = 1
                    If Interest < Arr_HighestSavings(c, k, j, a, g, w, b) Or Arr_HighestSavings(c, k, j, a, g, w, b) = 0 Then
                        Arr_HighestSavings(c, k, j, a, g, w, b) = Interest
                        wsLowestReturn.Cells((k * 9) + 3, 1) = k
                        wsLowestReturn.Cells((k * 9) + (3 + a), j - 18 + c * 52 + g * 26 + b * 104 + w * 208) = Round(Arr_HighestSavings(c, k, j, a, g, w, b), 4)
                    End If
                End If
        'MsgBox ("Current years served " & k & " completed!")
                    Next w
                Next c
            Next g
        Next k
    Next j
'    If i = 0.07 Then
'        MsgBox ("at 7")
'    End If
Next i
'MsgBox ("Officer Calculations Are Complete")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("Calculations Are Complete at " & Now())
End Sub
```

What I can't figure out is how to speed it up.  Currently the code is taking a long time to execute (a day per percent). I'm sure if I can take all the true/false items then it would be faster. Or how to recognize the array value at that j, k, g, c, w, is already determined and skip it.

What the variables are doing is changing values on a different sheet to determine the age at which investments will equal a certain amount.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Last thing you want to have is any worksheet interaction whatsoever, anywhere in that nested loop. Then you'll want a `Select Case True` block for your 6 conditions, so that you don't need to evaluate all 6 conditions every single time when the first one is satisfied.

Comment: I've no idea what `if i < array(j,k,g,c,w)` could possibly mean.

Comment: *What the variables are doing is changing values on a different sheet* - but variables don't do that. Variables *hold values*. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Or better, put up your *actual*, working code for peer review on [codereview.se].

Comment: Try your code on a small amount of data and then repeat with a larger amount. When you hit the wall (too long execution time), recode your solution. Repeat as needed.

Comment: Sorry all, here is the code.

Comment: Wow. That has to be about the most bizarre way to "Clear values" that I've ever seen. You realize that `.Cells((k * 9) + (3 + a), j - 18 + c * 52 + g * 26 + b * 104 + w * 208)` will give you a deterministic set of addresses in that the loop iterations are hard coded, right? This is convoluted enough that I can't visualize the sheet you're working with, but wouldn't a named range be more appropriate?

Comment: An empty cell value will not be `Null`, it will be `Variant/Empty` ...pretty sure swapping `Null` for `Empty` slashes execution time by quite a lot, since unless I'm mistaken, `<> Null` will be `True` for *every single cell*.

Comment: With this many iterations, limiting the round trips to the spreadsheet is going to be key. Given that you have so many "state" variables that you're working with (officer v. enlisted), (continuation, non-continuation), (withdrawal rate, none), this seems like a good candidate for a class.  Also, the line `Set Found(0) = wsSummary.Range("F38")` makes me think you're using the worksheet to calculate your results.  What's in that cell? Do you *need* to calculate on the worksheet?

Comment: The worksheet is calculating the investment values for every year of service (0 to 40) then calculates the expected value at age 60.  The Found(0) and Found(1) are referencing cells in the worksheet which account for inflation (0 is unadjusted and 1 is adjusted). I could probably take the worksheet and make it code within memory but I'm not familiar with how to do it. Most of the formulas in the worksheet are FV formulas.

Comment: OK, that's why this is taking on the order of months to complete. You can use the built in VBA [FV function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fv-function) instead of relying on functions in the cells on the worksheet. If you're using the worksheet simply to store the data for your calculation, I'd suggest defining a class or [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement) to store related data, then just make an array of that.